# How to determine if an input element has "checked" attribute in Python Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

There is a radio button whose buttons are controlled by `<input/>`. Its code is this:

```
<input id="IsEmployementProvided_0" name="IsEmployementProvided" type="radio" value="1" style="" xpath="1">

<input checked="checked" id="IsEmployementProvided_1" name="IsEmployementProvided" type="radio" value="0" xpath="1" style="">
```

As can be seen, the difference is the attribute "checked". So I am trying to find which one has a dot inside it, I mean which one has an attribute "checked". Here what I tried:

```
if(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='IsEmployementProvided_1']").get_attribute("checked").contains("checked")):
   print("value = "+driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='IsEmployementProvided_1']").get_attribute("checked").text)
```

Here error comes: Element has no attribute "contains". I am trying to determine if element has attribute "checked". Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to get the value of `checked` you get `true`:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='IsEmployementProvided_1']").get_attribute("checked")

#Output
'true'
```

Whereas, it returns `None` for the other radio button, `IsEmployementProvided_0`.

So, you can do something like this:

```
if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='IsEmployementProvided_1']").get_attribute("checked") == 'true':
    print('This is for checked!')
    # Do something

# OR simply skip the "== true" part.

if driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='IsEmployementProvided_1']").get_attribute("checked"):
    print('This is for checked!')
    # Do something
```

---

Also, `find_elements_by_xpath` is deprecated. Please use `find_element` instead. You'll have to import `By` for this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: thanks, I found similar solution